# WebStorm disable TSLint of js files

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, tslint

I'm using WebStorm 2019.1

I've generated a project using the Angular CLI.

Everything works fine but I have one or two .js files in my project - e.g. `protractor.conf.js`

Within the IDE, TSLint is linting the .js files and showing loads of red. But I don't want TSLint to lint the .js files.

I know I could disable TSLint for this file but I'd rather configure my project correctly by doing this via `tsconfig.json` or `tslint.json` or if all else fails via WebStorm settings.

[image]

I've tried `"tslint.jsEnable": false` as described here - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/issues/261 - but I think this is for a different IDE. Any ideas how to do this via `tsconfig.json` or `tslint.json` or failing that via WebStorm settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 2019.1 `.js` files are linted if `jsRules` is present in `tslint.json` ([WEB-36890](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36890)). You can add `.js` files to `"exclude":` option in `tslint.json` if you don't want them to be linted:

```
"linterOptions": {
    "exclude": ["**/*.js"]
}
```

This change will be reverted in 2019.1.1 - there will be the checkbox that existed in previous versions - **Process JS files**, off by default

Comment: This does not work for me. I'm downgrading for the mean time.

Comment: Also does not work for me. This is a pretty annoying bug. For small projects, I am working with `/* tslint:disable */`, but that is a really bad solution for bigger projects with both `ts` and `js` files...

Comment: need to add the .ts files as well, so: "exclude": ["**/*.js", "**/*.ts"]

Answer (score 1):

As @lena says it will be fixed in 2019.1.1 ([WEB-38096](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38096))

Comment: Got "unfixed" againhttps://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38096#focus=Comments-27-3376791.0-0